# How to install a package using apt-get in ubuntu container inside Docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have installed docker on windows 10. After that, pull the `ubuntu` container. After running the container with this `docker run -t -i --privileged ubuntu bash` or `docker run -it ubuntu` command, I've get this `root@7f72926f3608:/#` in console.

Then, try to install the `python` package using `apt-get` like `$sudo apt-get install python` or `apt-get install python`, but I've gotten the following error in console:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python
```

Hence, *the question is how can I install a package in ubuntu container inside docker?*

Comment: @jww Again here. Of course this post is related to development (development on ubuntu in windows docker). For example see this post: stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-edi‌​tor Also, there are many posts similar to this.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce thank you : ) Indeed, the reason for the downvote was removed by the downvoter and it is not valid anymore : )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run `apt-get update` and then install packages.

Comment: run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` within one command: `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python`